# Firebase JsonMappingException: Can't deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I run this to mock some data into my firebase reference:

```
    String id = firebase.push().getKey();
    FirebaseSchool school = new FirebaseSchool(id, "Test school", "Test city", "Test address");
    firebase = firebase.child(id);
    firebase.setValue(school);

    id = firebase.child("rooms").push().getKey();
    FirebaseRoomReference roomReference = new FirebaseRoomReference(id, "Test room", "Test owner");
    firebase.child("rooms").child(id).setValue(roomReference);

    id = firebase.child("rooms").push().getKey();
    FirebaseRoomReference roomReference2 = new FirebaseRoomReference(id, "Test room 2", "Test owner 2");
    firebase.child("rooms").child(id).setValue(roomReference2);
```

Which creates the following json:

```
"schools" : {
    "-K9LoPw-o0dOGAdWYqBF" : {
      "address" : "Test city",
      "city" : "Test address",
      "id" : "-K9LoPw-o0dOGAdWYqBF",
      "name" : "Test school",
      "rooms" : {
        "-K9LoPwDuzW-d19432kD" : {
          "id" : "-K9LoPwDuzW-d19432kD",
          "name" : "Test room",
          "ownerName" : "Test owner"
        },
        "-K9LoPwFPTrwSpUs0dZS" : {
          "id" : "-K9LoPwFPTrwSpUs0dZS",
          "name" : "Test room 2",
          "ownerName" : "Test owner 2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

as suggested I changed the Map<> to a List<> in my response class:

```
public class FirebaseSchool {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    private List<FirebaseUserReference> admins;
    private List<FirebaseRoomReference> rooms;


    public List<FirebaseUserReference> getAdmins() {
        return admins;
    }

    public void setAdmins(List<FirebaseUserReference> admins) {
        this.admins = admins;
    }

    public List<FirebaseRoomReference> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public void setRooms(List<FirebaseRoomReference> rooms) {
        this.rooms = rooms;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

but when I try to read a school using `snapshot.getValue(FirebaseSchool.class)` I get the following error:

```
com.firebase.client.FirebaseException: Failed to bounce to type
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: java.io.StringReader@dbf0e0f; line: 1, column: 44] (through reference chain: com.usehomeroom.vasuki.data.entities.firebase.FirebaseSchool["rooms"])
```

Comment: Can you add a piece of sample JSON as **text**? Preferably with a bit more data than in the screenshot. You can easily get this from your Firebase dashboard by clicking the Export button. That's also a great opportunity to strip the JSON back to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem **and** include the getters into your code. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Hey, I've edited my answer. Also, I was wondering if there was a way to push() using the Firebase App Dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data structure is being mapped to an array, not a map. I'm somewhat surprised about that, since your first index is 1 (not 0). But the error message is pretty explicit about what it's trying to do.

So to solve the problem, map the rooms to an `List` or array:

```
private List<FirebaseRoomReference> rooms;
```

To prevent this type of problem it is *highly* recommended to not use numeric indexes. Either use the values generated by `push()` or prefix your numbers with a fixed string, so that there's never any confusion about what type it is: `room_1`, `room_2`, etc.

### Update

I can read your updated JSON with this:

```
public static class FirebaseRoomReference {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String ownerName;

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getOwnerName() { return ownerName; }
}

public static class FirebaseSchool {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;
    //private List<FirebaseUserReference> admins;
    private Map<String, FirebaseRoomReference> rooms;

    //public List<FirebaseUserReference> getAdmins() { return admins; }

    public Map<String, FirebaseRoomReference> getRooms() {
        return rooms;
    }

    public String getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getAddress() { return address; }
    public String getCity() { return city; }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/35109413");
    ref.child("schools").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
            System.out.println(snapshot.getValue(FirebaseSchool.class));
        }
    });
```

Things I changed:

- I marked the POJO classes as static, since I include them as inner classes in my test program.
- I removed the user admins, since they're not present in your JSON
- I changed your List to a Map, since you're now using string keys

Before I change that last point, I got the same error message you did.

Comment: I was initially using an ArrayList but that would work only when the indices were ordered 0-N. I read elsewhere on stackoverflow to use a map but I get JsonMappingExceptions either way.